# seaborn Boxplot color Reverse

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, reverse

I have This Image:
[image]

And i want to this.:
[image]

Previously on this site, I found the code to convert the color as follows.
But I did not back up and lost data.
I want to make the above figure as below.
I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import getpass
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects

Variable = str(input())
In = []
In = Variable.split(" ")


username = getpass.getuser()

Data = pd.read_csv('c:/users/'+username+'/desktop/'+Variable+'.csv')

print(Data)

box = sns.boxplot(x="5PART",y="Sample",hue="Group" ,data = Data,color="k")
plt.show()
```

I tried cmap but it didn't work in Boxplot.
When Color was set to "w", the color gradient did not appear.
When the color was set to Grays, the G1 data was not completely black.

Either way, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Seaborn has the `palette` keyword instead of `cmap`.  A palette accepts many more types of data types, including `cmap` or just the name of a colormap.  So, you could try `sns.boxplot(...., palette='Greys'])` or `'Greys_r'` for a reversed map.

Comment: Thank you. Color Reverse was possible using the Palette function.
"  sns.boxplot(...., palette='"light:#000_r")  "